# How do I start a Jlist with the first item is selected?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, japplet

I want to know how to start a `JList` with the first item selected when I click a button.

Here is what I have:

```
if(e.getSource() ==bButton)
{
  lQty.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```

Comment: This only works when i have already selected an item.

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: If there isn't a selected item in the Jlist already it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure it works. e.g.,

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class JListFun {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final JList<String> list = new JList<String>(new String[]{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"});
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
      JButton btn = new JButton(new AbstractAction() {
         {
            putValue(NAME, "Press Me");
         }

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            list.setSelectedIndex(0);
         }
      });
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(scrollPane);
      panel.add(btn);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
   }
}
```

If it doesn't work for you, you need to ***show us*** with compilable runnable code as shown above.

Comment: Never mind it was something else that was causing a problem. But thanks for your quick response and help :D

Comment: @user3482995: which is *why* you should ask a complete question, one with code that shows us the problem, else you force us to guess what may be wrong in code not shown. But I'm glad that you've fixed it.

Comment: @user3482995: but please do check out the [minimal example program link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as this will tell you what you need to post next time.